# Row and Column Indices for 2-D array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a matrix mask with dimensions 512*512. I want to iterate through the matrix to find the row and column number for those values where mask(i,j) == 0

I am trying to use the below code but without any luck yet!

```
mask = (X < 0.1 | X > 0.9);  % //conditions for stability; mask is a matrx of 0s and 1s only
for i = 1:512
    for j = 1:512
%         if mask(i,j) == 0
            [r,c] =find(mask(i,j)==0);

        end
    end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is `[r, c] = find(mask)` what you want?

Comment: You don't need all those complicated measures, just use this - `[r,c] = find(mask==0);`

Comment: or to find the zeros `[r,c]=find(~mask)` which is equivalent to `[r,c]=find(mask==0)`

Comment: yes but it returns two separate row vectors;however, i want it in 1 matrix...will be helpful if you can edit in the above code your changes directly..@Divakar

Comment: to explain further, would be helpful if my final output is a matrix which is showing me the [row,column] as elements which match the above condition

Comment: @KashifNawaz Yes that's what you will get. You would have two vectors of rows and columns as `r` and `c` that match the condition. Have you tried the suggested code?

Comment: @Divakar: yes and as I mentioned above i would need the output in matrix format as I would need this data for manipulation later

Comment: Come on! `matrix = [r(:) c(:)]` !!